# [Insert Destination [26]] Error: Column "GovtProgYN" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types

Tags: sql

I am executing an ETL process and getting captioned error:

> source datatype is char(1) and destination datatype is nchar(2)

How do I insert data from `char` to `nchar`?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what platform you are using but you need to tell it to convert.  Something like

```
 SELECT CAST(GOVTPROGYN as NCHAR(2)) FROM TABLENAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY
```

or

```
 SELECT CAST(GOVTPROGYN as CHAR(1)) FROM TABLENAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY
```

Comment: etl package ms visual studio

Comment: @user2922376 -- visual studio is the development environment not the platform.  Platform is SQL Server, DB2, Oracle, mysql, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Per your title error, the `n` in `nchar` adds support for unicode, (same with `nvarchar` vs `varchar`). The data you are trying to insert is type `char`, but your destination field (`GovtProgYN`?) requires `nchar`.

Most SQL engines support a `CAST` function, which looks something like this: `CAST( field AS datatype )`. In your case, you would want to cast your insert value to `nchar(2)`.
*Example:*

```sql
INSERT INTO Table ( GovtProgYN ) 
VALUES ( CAST ( @value AS nchar(2) )
```

Some SQL engines, like SQL Server, require you to designate unicode using the `N` prefix to a character string. If you are trying to manually insert a `nchar` value, use `N'c'` rather than `'c'`.
*Example:*

```sql
INSERT INTO Table ( GovtProgYN ) 
VALUES ( N'c' )
```

Comment: where can I find insert script in package ...?

Comment: Hey user, we don't know what technology you are using, so I'm not sure. Can you update your question with more information?